# How can I get JSF to log to log4j

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, log4j, tomcat7

I'm developing a JSF application and I want to use log4j rather than the default logger.

The default logger appears to log to standard out. I have some integration tests that use an embedded tomcat to run my application and the log output causes an out of memory error when run from the command lie on Windows. So what I want to do is use log4j, that's the chosen logger for the application anyway, and filter most of the JSF logs.

I have found a couple of bits on the web that suggest all I need to do put the log4j JAR in the class path with an appropriate log4j.properties and exclude the commons logging JAR. I've tried that and it does *not* work.

This is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
            xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
            xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
            metadata-complete="true"
            id="WebApp_ID" 
            version="3.0">

  <display-name>Embedded Tomcar</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <context-param>
    <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.ALLOW_JAVASCRIPT</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.PRETTY_HTML</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.DETECT_JAVASCRIPT</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.AUTO_SCROLL</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener</listener-class>
  </listener>  

</web-app>
```

The code to my prototype is also on github: https://github.com/pjgrenyer/EmbeddedTomcat

Comment: "I've tried that and it does work." - spelling mistake?

Comment: Doh! Yes, thank you for spotting it. I've corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider configuring your application for a Logging Facade that allows you to redirect all application logging from Log4j and Apache Commons Logging through a single source.  If the third party jar decided to use Apache Commons then nothing short of reverse engineering or customizing the available FOSS code is going to get it to use Log4j directly.

Most commonly distributed Java libraries will log through a Logging Facade rather than directly through Log4j or a similar logging implementation because they don't want unnecessary dependencies, although IMHO it has always been a point of confusion and pain for myself.  Apache Commons actually is a Logging Facade for that matter, but it sucks hard so I understand why you want to move away from it.

Check out SLF4J, recent versions of Hibernate require this dependency, so if you are using Hibernate you probably already have this on your classpath.

http://www.slf4j.org/

Comment: My parts of the application are writing to log4j without any problem. It's JSF writeing to log4j I have a problem with. I found this page:

http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html

And successfully substituted commons-logging-1.1.1.jar for jcl-over-slf4j.jar. However I cannot redirect the output to log4j, even though I've put slf4j-log4j12-1.6.4.jar in the class path.